# UINavigationController popToRootViewController and P

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller

I am working on app with UINavigation.

First view has two buttons, 'AddNew' and 'Show All'.

flow of app is :
When user selects first view, it will push ViewController with textView and a button.

This view will push another view controller with tableView to select one of the items,

after selection, this view push a viewcontroller with summary of selected Items and a button to save options.

When user tap on save button, it will do some calculations according to selected data, save values in database and pop to root view controller and open show all viewcontroller.

My Problem : 
I tried using poptorootviewcontroller on save button and pushviewcontroller on firstView's viewdidappear (checking with flag). but it seems that navigation controller's animation is not completed when I tried to push viewcontroller.

I also tried poptorootviewcontroller without animation, but not working.

I also tried on viewdidappear of firstViewcontroller, performselector:afterDelay: but still no success.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Thanks,

Comment: HOw much delay you had put in performselector:afterDelay. It should be greater than 0.5

Comment: I tried with 0.7 and 1.0.

Comment: so your problem is , the View is Pushed from `viewDidAppear`, but without animation.?

Comment: I want to popToRootViewcontroller from last view controller, and when it is on first view I want to push view controller. Like :  [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES]; and then  [self.navigationController pushViewController:showAllVC animated:YES];

Comment: What view controller are you trying to push to? Where in the sequence of controllers is it (or is it in another branch)? Why do't you go directly to it, rather than popping to the root view controller first?

Comment: Do you have some screen shot to describe it